# Detect the end of all animations in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to execute javascript events in my directive only when the animation is over:
My animation, made with ngAnimate, when I change a view, has a duration of 1200ms.

Is there an optimal solution to load my directive or events when it's fully loaded ?

Here's my experiment, who works, but I bet there is an other way :) :

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(!mainView.hasClass('ng-leave')){
    // view fully loaded
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried maybe broadcasting an event on the root scope when the animation completes - so that you don't have to poll for the class?

Comment: How would you do ? I prefer to not surcharge the rootScope, but if it's the only way, I'll handle that ^^

Comment: You could have a relay service instead that you inject into things that need to know when an async action completes.  But in a sense I kind of assumed this was an acceptable use of rootscope for passing state without coupling.